# Ошибка при создании экземпляра класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, функции, классы

Ошибка при создании экземпляра класса, аргументы импортируются из json-файла

````
import json
from duble import filename


# класс покупателя
class Buyer:
    def __int__(self, name, balance, purchases, products):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.purchases = purchases
        self.products = products

    # метод выводящий список продуктов и их стоимость, хронящийся в переменной класса
    def product_range(self):
        print("Продукты: \n")
        for product, price in self.products.items():
            print(product, price)
        print("\n")

    def my_name(self):
        print(self.name + "\n")

    def my_balance(self):
        print(self.balance + "\n")

    def my_purchases(self):
        print(self.purchases + "\n")

    def buy(self, product):
        if product in self.products.keys():
            self.purchases.append(product)
            self.balance -= self.products[product]
            with open(filename) as f_obj:
                data = json.load(f_obj)
                data["buyers"][self.name]["purchases"].append(product)
                data["buyers"][self.name]["balance"] -= self.products[product]
                data["balance"] += self.products[product]
            with open(filename, "w") as f:
                json.dump(data, f)
        else:
            print("Продукта нет в продаже")

# если json файл пуст, используется для создания базовой структуры
def make_sample(name, balance=100, m_balance=0):
    sample = {
        "buyers": {
            name: {
                "balance": balance,
                "purchases": [],
            }
        },
        "product_range": {
            "Колбаса": 10,
            "Сыр": 13,
            "Вода": 2,
        },
        "balance": m_balance,
        "admins": ["Admin"]
    }
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(sample, f)
        print(f"{name}, cоздан шаблон")


# добавляет нового пользователя в json файл
def add_buyer(name, balance=100, ):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    except:
        make_sample(name, balance)
    else:
        if name in data["buyers"].keys():
            print("Уже есть покупатель с таким именем")
        else:
            data["buyers"][name] = {
                "balance": balance,
                "purchases": [],
            }
            with open(filename, "w") as f:
                json.dump(data, f)


def make_objekt(name):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    except:
        make_sample(name)
    else:
        if name in data["buyers"]:
            print(name, data["buyers"][name]["balance"], data["buyers"][name]["purchases"], data["product_range"])
            # pycharm здесь выделяет аргументы и пишет "Unexpected argument"
            object_1 = Buyer(name, data["buyers"][name]["balance"], data["buyers"][name]["purchases"], data["product_range"])
        else:
            add_buyer(name)
            object_1 = Buyer(name, data["buyers"][name]["balance"], data["buyers"][name]["purchases"], data["product_range"])

# создаёт object_1 с именем
make_objekt("frodo")```
        
Ошибка:
D:\Python\Tasks\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\Python\Tasks\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Tasks\main.py", line 100, in <module>
    make_objekt("frodo")
  File "D:\Python\Tasks\main.py", line 94, in make_objekt
    object_1 = Buyer(name, a, data["buyers"][name]["purchases"], data["product_range"])
TypeError: Buyer() takes no arguments
frodo 100 [] {'Колбаса': 10, 'Сыр': 13, 'Вода': 2}

Process finished with exit code 1
````

Answer (score 2):

У вас опечатка в определении метода инициализации:

```
def __int__(self, name, balance, purchases, products):
```

Пропустили букву, надо `__init__`, а у вас `__int__`

Comment: Кажется, это одна из прямо типовых ошибок, много раз уже такое видел )